# Post with HTTPUrlConnection

Tags: java

I'm using HttpUrlConnection to connect a web service where I have a form and a button.

The part in the source code is:

```
    <form action="main.php4?page=markt3art=UIN=484504321483db0fc35d1e8e660b99c8&x=&y=filled=1" method="POST">
        <input type="hidden" value="" name="p"></input>
        <input type="hidden" value="1755219" name="buy2f8d0"></input>
        <input type="hidden" value="1755219" name="buy"></input>
        <input type="text" value="323" size="9" maxlength="16" name="teilkauf"></input>
        <img width="1" hspace="20" height="1" src="pics/leer.gif"></img>
        <input class="send" type="submit" value=" buy "></input>
    </form>
```

What I'm doing is: (www is the website http:// ...)

```
            URL url = new URL(www);
            HttpURLConnection conexion = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            String forSending = "1";
            String charset = "UTF-8";

            String stringToSend = URLEncoder.encode(forSending, charset);

            conexion.setDoOutput(true);
            conexion.setRequestMethod("POST");
            OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(
            conexion.getOutputStream());

            out.write("teilkauf=" + stringToSend);
            out.flush();
            out.close();
```

But it doesn't work. Any help? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make a POST request to the form's action, not the site where form is located.

Form is like a front-end for the backend server, when you click submit browser builds a request to the action.

So instead of POSTing to the form's location POST to main.php4?page=markt3art=UIN=484504321483db0fc35d1e8e660b99c8&x=&y=filled=1

Comment: Do I only have to change www (the website) by http://...main.php4?page=markt3art=UIN=484504321483db0fc35d1e8e660b99c8&x=&y=filled=1? Because it doesn't work. (Sorry for my english).

Comment: You probably need to acquire that UIN token every time you want to POST that data.